Getting selected items from NextUI-Table
I'm absolutely new to JS and NextUI. I work with C# and DotNET normally.
I need to build a table with items that are selectable and at the click of a button, all the selected items should get passed to a 'use server' function that accepts a JSON-Array.
Now I'm stuck at getting the selected items from the table.
Here is what I tried, following some tutorials:
// ...

const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = React.useState(new Set([]));

return (
    <section className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 py-8 md:py-10">
      <div className="inline-block max-w-lg text-center justify-center">
        <h2 className={subtitle({ class: "mt-4" })}>
          Bitte die zu entfernenden Rezensionen auswählen:
        </h2>
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
        <Table
          color="primary"
          selectionMode="multiple"
          aria-label="Example static collection table"
          isStriped
          selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
          onSelectionChange={setSelectedKeys}
        >
          <TableHeader columns={columns}>
            {(column) => <TableColumn key={column.key}>{column.label}</TableColumn>}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody items={reviews}>
            {(item) => (
              <TableRow key={item.key}>
                {(columnKey) => <TableCell>{getKeyValue(item, columnKey)}</TableCell>}
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
);

// ...

the item.key is a number as in all the tutorials, even on the NextUI documentation.
In VS-Code it gives me this message on the onSelectionChange method:
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Set<never>>>' is not assignable to type '(keys: Selection) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'keys' are incompatible.
    Type 'Selection' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Set<never>>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Set<never>>'.ts(2322)
selection.d.ts(39, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onSelectionChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MergeWithAs<Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<TableHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableElement>, HTMLTableElement>, "ref">, Omit<...>, TableProps, "table">'

If I run it, there is this message:

It's pretty frustrating.

Can you please show the entire code of the page.tsx? Also I think that you are not using the useState hook in a component, it should look something like this
const page = () => {  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = React.useState(new Set([])); return (//component stuff)  } export default page;
something like this

const [selectedGoodsID, setSelectedGoodsID] = useState<Selection>(new Set<string>())

<Table 
  aria-label="Controlled table example with dynamic content"
  selectionMode="multiple"
  onSelectionChange={(selected) => {
    setSelectedGoodsID(selected)
  }}
>


The docs' solution didn't work for me either. In order to get around this, I had to pass a new Set as the new value:
onSelectionChange={ (keys: Selection) => setSelectedKeys(new Set(keys)) }


I ran into the same problem. The issue here is that Selection is an ambiguous type.
You need to explicitly import the type from @nextui-org/react to use the React type and not the typescript type with the same name.
import React from 'react';

const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = React.useState<Selection>(new Set());

--> Mismatched type error
import { Selection } from '@nextui-org/react';
import React from 'react';

const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = React.useState<Selection>(new Set());

--> Works
